# Is data retrieved over SSL cached by the client browser?

Tags: ssl, caching

I know that data retrieved over SSL (https) is encrypted over the wire, but once it arrives at the browser, is it stored in the client's browser cache?  If so, is it stored encrypted or in plain text?

This probably depends on the browser, so perhaps different browsers do different things?  Modern browsers better behaved than outdated ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is browser-specific. For example, Firefox has a preference about this in about:config [see this article in Mozilla's KB](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl). I don't know about other browsers (IE might have something in advanced security settings).

Comment: Ah, I see the default in Firefox is NOT to cache the SSL-retrieved content.  Nice link, thanks.

Comment: For Internet Explorer, the setting resides at Tools > Internet Options... > Advanced tab > Security section > Do not save encrypted pages to disk. Appears to be unchecked by default.

Comment: in firefox that setting was reversed in 2010 , so all ssl resources are cached by default unless cache-control header overrides.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the standard [Cache-Control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) HTTP header to control the client's behaviour. It is possible to disable caching, e.g. `Cache-Control: no-cache`.

As far as I know, most desktop browsers store the cache unencrypted.